# Trying to write to a database but no response

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android:How to write to SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168638/androidhow-to-write-to-sql-database)

I enter data into a form and on press of the button the strings should be sent to the database  and I have a dialog box to open if writing was successful however, I'm getting no response.

Edit: I identified the error as " AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
However my primary key is an integer?

```
public class AddCourse extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button sqlAddModule;
EditText sqlModuleCode, sqlModuleName, sqlModuleStart, sqlModuleEnd, sqlModuleLocation, sqlModuleComments;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_course);

        sqlAddModule= (Button)findViewById(R.id.addToDatabase);
        sqlModuleCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.labelEditModuleCode);
        sqlModuleName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.labelEditModuleFull);
        sqlModuleLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.labelEditModuleLocation);
        sqlModuleComments = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.labelEditModuleComments);

        sqlAddModule.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

        public void onClick (View addModuleButton) 
        {
            boolean didItWork = true;
            try{
            String moduleCode = sqlModuleCode.getText().toString();
            String moduleName = sqlModuleName.getText().toString();
            String moduleLocation = sqlModuleLocation.getText().toString();
            String moduleComments = sqlModuleComments.getText().toString();

            database entry = new database(AddCourse.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(moduleCode, moduleName,moduleLocation, moduleComments);
            entry.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
            }finally{ if(didItWork){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this) ;
                d.setTitle("BooYa!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }


            }

            finish();

        }    

}
```

SQL Class

```
public class database {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_MODULECODE = "module_code";
    public static final String KEY_MODULENAME = "module_name";
    public static final String KEY_MODULETYPE = "module_type";
    public static final String KEY_MODULEDAY = "module_day";
    public static final String KEY_MODULESTART = "module_start";
    public static final String KEY_MODULEEND = "module_end";
    public static final String KEY_MODULELOCATION = "module_location";
    public static final String KEY_MODULECOMMENTS = "module_comments";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "module_database";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "my_modules";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper myHelper;
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase moduleDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_MODULECODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_MODULENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_MODULELOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_MODULECOMMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL,);"
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABEL IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }


    }

    public database(Context c){
        myContext = c;
    }

    public  database open()throws SQLException{
        myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
        moduleDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
    myHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String moduleCode, String moduleName,  String moduleLocation, String moduleComments) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MODULECODE,moduleCode);
        cv.put(KEY_MODULENAME,moduleName);
        cv.put(KEY_MODULELOCATION,moduleLocation);
        cv.put(KEY_MODULECOMMENTS,moduleComments);
        return moduleDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: This is the same question as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13168638/1267661), but without the error...

Comment: I noticed I that I had left out the setOnClickListner which solved the error but now logCat is not displaying any errors except for the garbage collector freeing memory.

Comment: I removed it and added it back in but it made no difference. My mistake is either in my onClick Method or in the database class.but can'nt see to find it.

Comment: Ugh...typical it was an extra comma at the end of my create Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your database class:
`" INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "` 
that is not the correct spelling of "INTEGER", as you probably already know. Also, take note of `db.execSQL("DROP TABEL IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);`

Comment: Thanks I actually didn't cop the spelling error. Quick question is it ok to leave the method you mentioned blank or is there an alternate statement required instead of DROP TABEL IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE to ensure the data remains?

Comment: It's `TABLE`, not TABEL.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with my code was an extra comma at the of CREATETABLE

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_MODULECODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_MODULENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_MODULELOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_MODULECOMMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );
```